# Is dispatch function returned from useDispatch hook synchronous with async thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux-thunk, redux-toolkit

**Async thunk**:

```
const getMovies = createAsyncThunk('recommended/getMovies', async () =>{
    const result = await api.getRecommendedMovies();
    console.log('first')
    return result;
});
```

**Function that uses dispatch function from *useDispatch* hook**:

```
const getMovies = (page) => {console.log(moviesData)
    const moviesData = dispatch(recommendedMoviesActions.getMovies());
    console.log('second');
};
```

The console logs are as follows:

1. 'second'
2. 'first'

Why did this result like that? Shouldn't it be 1. 'first, 2. 'second' because dispatching is synchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createAsyncThunk` returns a standard Redux thunk action creator. You return a promise from the thunk(`async/await`), `dispatch(recommendedMoviesActions.getMovies())` returns a promise, so you should wait for the promise to resolve before doing additional work. See [Unwrapping Result Actions](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#unwrapping-result-actions)

```
import { configureStore, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const api = {
  getRecommendedMovies: () => Promise.resolve(),
};

const getMovies = createAsyncThunk('recommended/getMovies', async () => {
  const result = await api.getRecommendedMovies();
  console.log('first');
  return result;
});

const store = configureStore({ reducer() {} });
// second, first
// store.dispatch(getMovies());
// console.log('second');

// first, second
store.dispatch(getMovies()).then(() => {
  console.log('second');
});
```